# IoT Hub route query does not match on message body

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I'm facing some issues with filtering on message body in the Azure IoT Hub. Is this still not supported? The tests go through, but when I try real messages from the device everything is hitting the fallback and not the intended route.¨

In other words:

```
 //this is working when adding property to message in the device code
    temperature > 30
//this is not working when message contains json object without using any properties
    $body.temperature > 30
```

Do we still need to use the message properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature (such as a filtering on the $body) requires setup the following message system properties:

```
message.ContentType = "application/json";
message.ContentEncoding = "utf-8";
```

See more details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/iot-hub-message-routing-now-with-routing-on-message-body/).